# Stack a Pandas dataframe replacing NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I was having trouble finding this answered already. I have sample data below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'James', 1: 'James', 2: 'James', 3: 'John', 4: 'Johh', 5: 'John'},
                  'Final': {0: 'foo', 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: 'too', 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan},
                  'Alpha': {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Z', 3: 'X', 4: 'Y', 5: 'Z'},
                    'Two': {0: '1234', 1: '5678', 2:np.nan , 3: 'abdc', 4: 'efgh', 5: np.nan} 
                 })
```

[image]

I want to transform this so that all of the data is on top of each other and replacing the null values like this:

[image]

Comment: It looks like your different columns have different data types. It wouldn't make much sense to have them under one column ? But if you do need it that way I guess `.set_index('name').stack()` will do what you need -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get a series, add .to_frame() to get a dataframe:

```
df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
Name
James     foo
James       X
James    1234
James       Y
James    5678
James       Z
John      too
John        X
John     abdc
Johh        Y
Johh     efgh
John        Z
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `melt`:

```py
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'James', 1: 'James', 2: 'James', 3: 'John', 4: 'Johh', 5: 'John'},
                  'Final': {0: 'foo', 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: 'too', 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan},
                  'Alpha': {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Z', 3: 'X', 4: 'Y', 5: 'Z'},
                    'Two': {0: '1234', 1: '5678', 2:np.nan , 3: 'abdc', 4: 'efgh', 5: np.nan} 
                 })


df_melt = (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=['Final', 'Alpha', 'Two'], var_name='variable', value_name='value')
             .dropna()
             .drop(['variable'], axis=1)
             .sort_values(by='Name')
             .rename(columns = {'value' : 'Final'})
             .reset_index(drop=True)
             )

print(df_melt)
```

```
     Name Final
0   James   foo
1   James     X
2   James     Y
3   James     Z
4   James  1234
5   James  5678
6    Johh     Y
7    Johh  efgh
8    John   too
9    John     X
10   John     Z
11   John  abdc
```